# how to collect all values on objects laravel

Tags: laravel, object

i'm very new on laravel and get some problem here.

i' have some objects like bellow :

```
   {#420
  +"objects": array:1 [
    0 => {#421
      +"external_operator": "AND"
      +"internal_operator": "OR"
      +"values": array:1 [
        0 => 1321
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how to collect all values without access keys from object?
my expectation result :

```
array:1 [
      0 => {#421
        +"external_operator": "AND"
        +"internal_operator": "OR"
        +"values": array:1 [
          0 => 1321
        ]
      }
    ]
```

need help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$model->getAttributes();
```

and

```
$model->toArray();
```

**EDIT**

Do you need [get_object_vars](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)?

Comment: getAttributes() and toArray() not working, because i get the result from json_decode(json array of object)

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what you really want. I've edited anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you're use eloquent object
it's simple

```
$model = Model::all();
```

and get whatever you want

```
echo $model->value1;
```